# APEX SOQL retrieve values dynamically based on string variable

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

In my apex code i have a variable `resultField` and a `List<Id> objIds`. What i need is a `List<My_Obj__c> objs = [select Id, :resultField from My_Obj__c where Id in :objIds];`. This is not working because apparantly i can't specify `:resultField` even though `:objIds` work in the query. Is there a way to do it other than string concatinations.

Comment: @RahulSharma  i am trying to select a second field dynamically from variable resultField. That's why there is that ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Apex bindings in the `SELECT` or `FROM` clauses of a SOQL query. Bindings are available in the `WHERE` clause.

You'll need to use [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to construct your query as a string concatenation, as you mention - there's not another way to build a query with dynamic values in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: will it let me do `Database.query('select Id, ' + resultField + ' from My_Obj__c where Id in :objIds')`. Will it let me bind `:objIds`

Comment: Yes. You can still do simple binding to Apex variables.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce only takes bind variable in WHERE clause and not in the SELECT statement.

So, you need to perform String concatenation.